# Making sure each element in string array has only one space either side C#

Tags: c#, split, arrays

I have split the string already (which was Victoria Adelaide Mary/Wettin/" but now that I have split it, I need to make sure there ONLY ONE space either side of each element in the array.

```
                detail = "Victoria Adelaide Mary/Wettin/";
                name = "";
                string[] detailArray = detail.Split('/');

                foreach (string s in detailArray)
                {
                    name += s;
                }
```

The word "Wettin" for example does not have a space either side. What would you suggest I do?

Thank you :)

ps. input -> "Wettin" (which is one of the elements of the array
    output -> " Wettin"

in full

- "Victoria" becomes "Victoria " (as it is the first element of the
  array)
- "Adelaide" becomes " Adelaide "
- "Mary" becomes " Mary "
- "Wettin" becomes " Wettin" (as it is the last element of the array

**I need a space at the end of the first element of the array, space at the beginning of the last element of the array and make sure each word in the middle only has ONE space between them**

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please post a few samples of input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all names into separate items in array, you can use:

```
string[] detailArray = detail.Replace('/', ' ').Split(' ');
```

To get it together in `name` variable:

```
        string detail = "Victoria Adelaide Mary/Wettin/";
        string name = "";

        string[] detailArray = detail.Replace('/', ' ').Split(' ');

        foreach (string s in detailArray)
        {
            name += s + " ";
        }
        // trim last space character
        name = name.TrimEnd(' ');
```

Comment: it's not efficient to build strings with concatenation (the + symbol) when the strings aren't known at runtime. Also, the Replace/Split combination in the first code block is redundant, you may as well use a single split with a forward slash.

Comment: I know. But for names I think it's fine, because there is only few items. Using StringBuilder seems to be heavy machinery here for me.

Comment: The concern is not for the time it requires to do a string concatenation but rather the impact it has on memory (garbage collections more frequently)

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = string.Format(" {0} ", string.Join(" ", detail.Split('/')));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx - String.Join

(Adding the below after question closed as I think it's a bit more efficient)

`string name = string.Format(" {0} ", string.Replace('/', ' '));`